# How to remove Crash Dump Files under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bsod, sql-server, minidumps

My Windows 7 hard drive suddenly filled up today.  After doing some research, I downloaded and  ran WinDirStat.  This identified that 29% of my hard drive was occupied by Crash Dump Files (*.mdmp).  I have had frequent blue screens on the system since I updated to Windows 7.

In any case, how can I remove these files?

EDIT:  Upon further review and troubleshooting, I realized the files were caused by an issue with SQL Server installed on my machine.  It was actually crashing and the cause of the mdmp files being created.  They were stored in the SQL install directory.  A bit more research on my part would have found this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Disk Cleanup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Delete-files-using-Disk-Cleanup), built-in with Windows, can perform this task for you;
you must be administrator to perform this task. Another way is to just remove the files you have found through WinDirStat. As long as you remove the *.mdmp files and no other important system files...

You might want to examine your event logs though to see why so many crashes have occured! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this did in the end help me find the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reputation! It feels like a battle to me to get up, new users do not tend to upvote and accept answer it seems. But well... I'll have patience. :-)